# #1054 - Unknown column 'tidbitz' in 'field list'

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Via phpmyadmin I dropped the column 'tidbitz' from a table.

Now any time I try to write to that table I get this error. The column is gone and it's not included in any of the queries that I am running. I know the syntax is correct for my queries. I can't even edit data using phpmyadmin, I still get this error.

I have tried: restarting the mysql server, restarting apache, defragmenting and optimizing the table...

Why is this ghost column sticking around?

Comment: When and where is this error appearing?

Comment: @ChristopherKenney Please see the title of my post.

Comment: @Jim When - any time I run a query writing to this table. Where - in php, mysql cli, phpmyadmin, you name it.

Comment: can you show us the code you've tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up fixing my problem by creating another identical table, writing all of the data from table one to table two, dropping table one, and renaming table two to table one.

So, the problem is fixed, but I'm still curious to know if anyone has encountered this before and what the root cause is.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Just encountered the same problem. In my case it was caused by an insert trigger that was running a query which was using the no-longer-existing column.